# Downloading .mp4 from URL

Tags: php, html

Hi guys so i'm trying to make a video downloadable from CDN, i tried these but it doesn't work it just opens up the code. Is there any other way? I tried using just html and put the link in the ahref and it still doesn't work. Thank you

index.html

```
<a href="download.php" target="_blank"> Download </a>
```

download.php

```
header("Content-disposition: inline; filename=https://jalpai.fruithosted.net/dl/n/5yAtd4WcqDs60kKR/fscslmftlflcqrcd/_8uz9ekpVndEEkYA6fyLk027J8VkgpkCd9ZeMTY6MC5ZU98Uy9hUa5Atp7Ou5yroih4R_1x-L417pbMLxoER0cMn4AMd1jnbsc470JsLM5L7xerZIwM5ShswARYr3SP5--P1qZnpUmYIUBcT6-lJec24HuKPlWMoS8LYERqy3GIC7vNuM7-1H-xU1sL3jq5kG_rIkyk6Iv8vCXQIusSCsk7I3iAmTuwXW9IjrBvX3Q9mAeXMHAIZ3MSvSdDzYMLlAkaPqcZEZQZSHl7ACcWdcxHhVyl87EMIw__a--j8jv3bpVih-fXYu1wc8xKt5T3D0cJjqNxawE4fkeVI_H90kpjScNkIPiJW8IwK7sDHuEM-OgD74VeLVJ0_OxE4uV6u0eEL4FhB61Gjfk2owQnksSSqEf8Y2Ax9iWDbYnPKTNl-ir3f49gguLFiYl-O6bxy/Big+Hero+6.2014.HD+1080p.mp4%20%22,%20'r'));%20//https://jalpai.fruithosted.net/dl/n/5yAtd4WcqDs60kKR/fscslmftlflcqrcd/_8uz9ekpVndEEkYA6fyLk027J8VkgpkCd9ZeMTY6MC5ZU98Uy9hUa5Atp7Ou5yroih4R_1x-L417pbMLxoER0cMn4AMd1jnbsc470JsLM5L7xerZIwM5ShswARYr3SP5--P1qZnpUmYIUBcT6-lJec24HuKPlWMoS8LYERqy3GIC7vNuM7-1H-xU1sL3jq5kG_rIkyk6Iv8vCXQIusSCsk7I3iAmTuwXW9IjrBvX3Q9mAeXMHAIZ3MSvSdDzYMLlAkaPqcZEZQZSHl7ACcWdcxHhVyl87EMIw__a--j8jv3bpVih-fXYu1wc8xKt5T3D0cJjqNxawE4fkeVI_H90kpjScNkIPiJW8IwK7sDHuEM-OgD74VeLVJ0_OxE4uV6u0eEL4FhB61Gjfk2owQnksSSqEf8Y2Ax9iWDbYnPKTNl-ir3f49gguLFiYl-O6bxy/Big+Hero+6.2014.HD+1080p.mp4");
header("Content-type: video/mp4:"); 
readfile("https://jalpai.fruithosted.net/dl/n/5yAtd4WcqDs60kKR/fscslmftlflcqrcd/_8uz9ekpVndEEkYA6fyLk027J8VkgpkCd9ZeMTY6MC5ZU98Uy9hUa5Atp7Ou5yroih4R_1x-L417pbMLxoER0cMn4AMd1jnbsc470JsLM5L7xerZIwM5ShswARYr3SP5--P1qZnpUmYIUBcT6-lJec24HuKPlWMoS8LYERqy3GIC7vNuM7-1H-xU1sL3jq5kG_rIkyk6Iv8vCXQIusSCsk7I3iAmTuwXW9IjrBvX3Q9mAeXMHAIZ3MSvSdDzYMLlAkaPqcZEZQZSHl7ACcWdcxHhVyl87EMIw__a--j8jv3bpVih-fXYu1wc8xKt5T3D0cJjqNxawE4fkeVI_H90kpjScNkIPiJW8IwK7sDHuEM-OgD74VeLVJ0_OxE4uV6u0eEL4FhB61Gjfk2owQnksSSqEf8Y2Ax9iWDbYnPKTNl-ir3f49gguLFiYl-O6bxy/Big+Hero+6.2014.HD+1080p.mp4%20%22,%20'r'));%20//https://jalpai.fruithosted.net/dl/n/5yAtd4WcqDs60kKR/fscslmftlflcqrcd/_8uz9ekpVndEEkYA6fyLk027J8VkgpkCd9ZeMTY6MC5ZU98Uy9hUa5Atp7Ou5yroih4R_1x-L417pbMLxoER0cMn4AMd1jnbsc470JsLM5L7xerZIwM5ShswARYr3SP5--P1qZnpUmYIUBcT6-lJec24HuKPlWMoS8LYERqy3GIC7vNuM7-1H-xU1sL3jq5kG_rIkyk6Iv8vCXQIusSCsk7I3iAmTuwXW9IjrBvX3Q9mAeXMHAIZ3MSvSdDzYMLlAkaPqcZEZQZSHl7ACcWdcxHhVyl87EMIw__a--j8jv3bpVih-fXYu1wc8xKt5T3D0cJjqNxawE4fkeVI_H90kpjScNkIPiJW8IwK7sDHuEM-OgD74VeLVJ0_OxE4uV6u0eEL4FhB61Gjfk2owQnksSSqEf8Y2Ax9iWDbYnPKTNl-ir3f49gguLFiYl-O6bxy/Big+Hero+6.2014.HD+1080p.mp4");
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont need the php file just the html. Try this:

```
<a href="https://jalpai.fruithosted.net/dl/n/5yAtd4WcqDs60kKR/fscslmftlflcqrcd/_8uz9ekpVndEEkYA6fyLk027J8VkgpkCd9ZeMTY6MC5ZU98Uy9hUa5Atp7Ou5yroih4R_1x-L417pbMLxoER0cMn4AMd1jnbsc470JsLM5L7xerZIwM5ShswARYr3SP5--P1qZnpUmYIUBcT6-lJec24HuKPlWMoS8LYERqy3GIC7vNuM7-1H-xU1sL3jq5kG_rIkyk6Iv8vCXQIusSCsk7I3iAmTuwXW9IjrBvX3Q9mAeXMHAIZ3MSvSdDzYMLlAkaPqcZEZQZSHl7ACcWdcxHhVyl87EMIw__a--j8jv3bpVih-fXYu1wc8xKt5T3D0cJjqNxawE4fkeVI_H90kpjScNkIPiJW8IwK7sDHuEM-OgD74VeLVJ0_OxE4uV6u0eEL4FhB61Gjfk2owQnksSSqEf8Y2Ax9iWDbYnPKTNl-ir3f49gguLFiYl-O6bxy/Big+Hero+6.2014.HD+1080p.mp4%20%22,%20'r'));%20//https://jalpai.fruithosted.net/dl/n/5yAtd4WcqDs60kKR/fscslmftlflcqrcd/_8uz9ekpVndEEkYA6fyLk027J8VkgpkCd9ZeMTY6MC5ZU98Uy9hUa5Atp7Ou5yroih4R_1x-L417pbMLxoER0cMn4AMd1jnbsc470JsLM5L7xerZIwM5ShswARYr3SP5--P1qZnpUmYIUBcT6-lJec24HuKPlWMoS8LYERqy3GIC7vNuM7-1H-xU1sL3jq5kG_rIkyk6Iv8vCXQIusSCsk7I3iAmTuwXW9IjrBvX3Q9mAeXMHAIZ3MSvSdDzYMLlAkaPqcZEZQZSHl7ACcWdcxHhVyl87EMIw__a--j8jv3bpVih-fXYu1wc8xKt5T3D0cJjqNxawE4fkeVI_H90kpjScNkIPiJW8IwK7sDHuEM-OgD74VeLVJ0_OxE4uV6u0eEL4FhB61Gjfk2owQnksSSqEf8Y2Ax9iWDbYnPKTNl-ir3f49gguLFiYl-O6bxy/Big+Hero+6.2014.HD+1080p.mp4" download> Download </a>
```

Inside the A tag you insert "download" to force save as instead of loading a page hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, it just opens the link not really making it downloadable that is why i made that php file :(

Comment: Adding download to the A tag normally fixed this for me (This is for Chrome, Firefox, Opera & possibly Microsoft Edge). Realistically its probably a browser issue and I don't think there's a way to make it force "save as" on every browser. sorry i couldn't help more

Comment: No problem bro, hopefully you find a decent solution soon ;)

Answer (score 0):

On the `download.php` file.

```
$readfile="https://jalpai.fruithosted.net/dl/n/5yAtd4WcqDs60kKR/fscslmftlflcqrcd/_8uz9ekpVndEEkYA6fyLk027J8VkgpkCd9ZeMTY6MC5ZU98Uy9hUa5Atp7Ou5yroih4R_1x-L417pbMLxoER0cMn4AMd1jnbsc470JsLM5L7xerZIwM5ShswARYr3SP5--P1qZnpUmYIUBcT6-lJec24HuKPlWMoS8LYERqy3GIC7vNuM7-1H-xU1sL3jq5kG_rIkyk6Iv8vCXQIusSCsk7I3iAmTuwXW9IjrBvX3Q9mAeXMHAIZ3MSvSdDzYMLlAkaPqcZEZQZSHl7ACcWdcxHhVyl87EMIw__a--j8jv3bpVih-fXYu1wc8xKt5T3D0cJjqNxawE4fkeVI_H90kpjScNkIPiJW8IwK7sDHuEM-OgD74VeLVJ0_OxE4uV6u0eEL4FhB61Gjfk2owQnksSSqEf8Y2Ax9iWDbYnPKTNl-ir3f49gguLFiYl-O6bxy/Big+Hero+6.2014.HD+1080p.mp4%20%22,%20'r'));%20//https://jalpai.fruithosted.net/dl/n/5yAtd4WcqDs60kKR/fscslmftlflcqrcd/_8uz9ekpVndEEkYA6fyLk027J8VkgpkCd9ZeMTY6MC5ZU98Uy9hUa5Atp7Ou5yroih4R_1x-L417pbMLxoER0cMn4AMd1jnbsc470JsLM5L7xerZIwM5ShswARYr3SP5--P1qZnpUmYIUBcT6-lJec24HuKPlWMoS8LYERqy3GIC7vNuM7-1H-xU1sL3jq5kG_rIkyk6Iv8vCXQIusSCsk7I3iAmTuwXW9IjrBvX3Q9mAeXMHAIZ3MSvSdDzYMLlAkaPqcZEZQZSHl7ACcWdcxHhVyl87EMIw__a--j8jv3bpVih-fXYu1wc8xKt5T3D0cJjqNxawE4fkeVI_H90kpjScNkIPiJW8IwK7sDHuEM-OgD74VeLVJ0_OxE4uV6u0eEL4FhB61Gjfk2owQnksSSqEf8Y2Ax9iWDbYnPKTNl-ir3f49gguLFiYl-O6bxy/Big+Hero+6.2014.HD+1080p.mp4";

$filename = basename($readfile); // Getting the base name of the file.

file_put_contents($filename,file_get_contents($readfile));
```

---

Tried with:

```
$video = 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4';

$filename = basename($video); // Getting the base name of the file.

file_put_contents($filename,file_get_contents($video));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the intention is to allow users the ability to download this movie simply by clicking on the hyperlink then perhaps modify `download.php` to the following

```
<?php    

    $filepath="https://jalpai.fruithosted.net/dl/n/5yAtd4WcqDs60kKR/fscslmftlflcqrcd/_8uz9ekpVndEEkYA6fyLk027J8VkgpkCd9ZeMTY6MC5ZU98Uy9hUa5Atp7Ou5yroih4R_1x-L417pbMLxoER0cMn4AMd1jnbsc470JsLM5L7xerZIwM5ShswARYr3SP5--P1qZnpUmYIUBcT6-lJec24HuKPlWMoS8LYERqy3GIC7vNuM7-1H-xU1sL3jq5kG_rIkyk6Iv8vCXQIusSCsk7I3iAmTuwXW9IjrBvX3Q9mAeXMHAIZ3MSvSdDzYMLlAkaPqcZEZQZSHl7ACcWdcxHhVyl87EMIw__a--j8jv3bpVih-fXYu1wc8xKt5T3D0cJjqNxawE4fkeVI_H90kpjScNkIPiJW8IwK7sDHuEM-OgD74VeLVJ0_OxE4uV6u0eEL4FhB61Gjfk2owQnksSSqEf8Y2Ax9iWDbYnPKTNl-ir3f49gguLFiYl-O6bxy/Big+Hero+6.2014.HD+1080p.mp4%20%22,%20'r'));%20//https://jalpai.fruithosted.net/dl/n/5yAtd4WcqDs60kKR/fscslmftlflcqrcd/_8uz9ekpVndEEkYA6fyLk027J8VkgpkCd9ZeMTY6MC5ZU98Uy9hUa5Atp7Ou5yroih4R_1x-L417pbMLxoER0cMn4AMd1jnbsc470JsLM5L7xerZIwM5ShswARYr3SP5--P1qZnpUmYIUBcT6-lJec24HuKPlWMoS8LYERqy3GIC7vNuM7-1H-xU1sL3jq5kG_rIkyk6Iv8vCXQIusSCsk7I3iAmTuwXW9IjrBvX3Q9mAeXMHAIZ3MSvSdDzYMLlAkaPqcZEZQZSHl7ACcWdcxHhVyl87EMIw__a--j8jv3bpVih-fXYu1wc8xKt5T3D0cJjqNxawE4fkeVI_H90kpjScNkIPiJW8IwK7sDHuEM-OgD74VeLVJ0_OxE4uV6u0eEL4FhB61Gjfk2owQnksSSqEf8Y2Ax9iWDbYnPKTNl-ir3f49gguLFiYl-O6bxy/Big+Hero+6.2014.HD+1080p.mp4";
    $filename=basename( $filepath );

    function sendfile( $filename=NULL, $filepath=NULL ){
        header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Length: ".(string)( filesize( $filepath ) ) );
        header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename={$filename}");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");

        if( $file = @fopen( $filepath, 'rb' ) ) {
            while( !@feof( $file ) and ( connection_status()==0 ) ) {
                print( fread( $file, 1024*8 ) );
                flush();
            }
            @fclose( $file );
        }
        return( ( connection_status()==0 ) and !connection_aborted() );
    }


    call_user_func( 'sendfile', $filename, $filepath );

?>
```

And then craft your hyperlink

```
<a href='download.php' target='_blank'>Download "Big+Hero+6.2014.HD+1080p.mp4"</a>
```

I'm not able to test with the given url from my local workstation nor even to download the file manually - hopefully it'll help but I might have misunderstood.